# Why is the image translated inside the div?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, scrollbar, center

I have an image `img` inside a DIV `modal`, and a button `+` at the bottom right. This button calls the function `imgfit()` that toggles the image view as "fit and center inside the window" or "100%" (i.e., 1:1 pixel). It works, except for the fact that the scrollbars do not allow me to scroll the top/left of the image: the image is displaced negatively inside the div when seen at 1:1.

How do I tell the scrollbars that they "forgot" part of the image at the top/right? You can see the problem [here](http://luis.impa.br/gal.html?srca=photo/1612_macros/olho-eu_Casa-170114-A_29232-rawa.jpg;photo/1703_aves/trovoada-de-bertoni_PNSB-170227-A_31444-rawa.jpg;photo/1703_aves/piolhinho-serrano_PNSB-170227-A_31627-rawa.jpg;photo/1703_aves/anambe-branco-de-rabo-preto_femea_PNSB-170227-A_31685-rawa.jpg&capa=olho;trovoada-de-bertoni%20(PNSB);piolhinho-serrano;anambe-branco-de-rabo-preto&forb=true) (make your browser window relatively small to better see the problem).

The button calls the following function `imgfit`:

```
function imgfit()
{
  if (fit) {
    img.style.minWidth = "0px";
    img.style.minHeight = "0px";
    img.style.maxWidth = "100vw";
    img.style.maxHeight = "100vh";
    modal.style.overflow = "hidden"; // Prevent scroll of fullsize image
  } else {
    img.style.maxWidth = 'none';
    img.style.maxHeight = 'none';
    img.style.minWidth = img.naturalWidth+"px";
    img.style.minHeight = img.naturalHeight+"px";
    modal.style.overflow = "auto"; // Allow scroll of fullsize image
  }
  fit = ! fit;
}
```

This is the `CSS` of the image and the modal div (if I remove the `align-items: center` and the `justify-content: center`, problem is gone, but image is not centered):

```
.modal {
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #000;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 touch-action: manipulation;
}

.img {
 cursor: no-drop;
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem thanks to the neat article [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-center-and-keep-focus-on-modal-image-using-mobile/289299/2) (I didn't know that *sitepoint.com* site). The culprit was the `position: absolute` thing. Changing to `display: grid` solved the issue:

```
.modal {
 display: grid;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%; 
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #000; 
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 touch-action: manipulation;
}

.img {
 grid-column: 1;
 grid-row: 1;
 cursor: no-drop;
 margin: auto;
 touch-action: manipulation;
}
```